# Table does not exist in spring data jpa

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

I am using MYSQL and JPA Repository for the database, but I am not able to create the database. I am getting errors while I am creating the database. I get the below types of errors.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table receipe add constraint FKa69t2bf4dc0w8491l2qkq4j8r foreign key (problem_id) references disease (problem_id)" via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:562) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:507) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:433) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:318) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1259) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
        at com.nillmani.hospitalmanagement.HospitalManagementApplicationKt.main(HospitalManagementApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hospital-management.receipe' doesn't exist
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
    
    2021-10-14 15:45:52.601  INFO 3112 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
    2021-10-14 15:45:52.619  INFO 3112 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
    2021-10-14 15:45:52.683  WARN 3112 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
    2021-10-14 15:45:53.029  INFO 3112 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
    2021-10-14 15:45:53.040  INFO 3112 --- [           main] c.n.h.HospitalManagementApplicationKt    : Started HospitalManagementApplicationKt in 3.65 seconds (JVM running for 4.396)
```

> application.yml

```yaml
    spring:
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital-management
        driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        username: root
        password:
      jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        show-sql: true
        hibernate:
          ddl-auto: update
```

> Reciepe.kt

```kotlin
    package com.nillmani.hospitalmanagement.entity
    
    import java.time.LocalDate
    import javax.persistence.*
    
    @Entity
    data class Receipe(
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ")
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ",allocationSize = 1,name = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ")
        val receipeId:Long=-1,
        val details :String="",
        val barcode : String ="",
        val drug_details: String="",
        val usage : String ="",
        val delivery_Date : LocalDate= LocalDate.now(),
        val diseaseId:Long=-1,//refere to  problmeID
        val patientId:Long=-1,
        val status : Int=0,
        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "problemId",referencedColumnName = "problemId")
        val disease: Disease ?=null,
    )
```

> I create the Database in phpMyAdmin Server. I provide @Entity
> annotation in my Reciepe data class but I am not able to create the
> table Recipe in hospital-management database.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the MySQL dependency in `pom.xml`?

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Update**

It seems something is wrong with your ManyToOne association.
First of all, you can define another name for the join column something like `disease_Id` it's the name that you give, But `referencedColumnName` should be the same as the name of the parent's property for example `diseaseId`(If id of your Disease entity is `diseaseId`)

Another thing, typically you don't need  `CascadeType.ALL` for the child side. Because it means when you delete just one `Receipe` record it removes the whole parent entity. You can handle cascade on another side for @OneToMany.

So I suggest remove cascade and/or change the name of join columns try again.

Comment: I have many entity class and Am able to create table for them , But I  Specifically Getting error While create the Table for Reciepe  Entity, Why this issue for Reciepe entity not for other entity

Comment: I update the answer check that.